# Row HASHBYTES in results

Tags: sql-server

I wonder if anyone can help me achieve this.  I have a row of 100 columns, 1st being the primary key.  I need to retrieve from each row in my query the primary key column and a HASHBYTES of the entire row, so the results would look like:

```
PK            Hash
000123        HASHVALUE1234567890ETC
```

I can get the entire row with this select statement:

```
SELECT hashbytes('sha1', (SELECT * From Table Where PK = 000123 FOR XML RAW))
```

I cannot however work out how to get the PK and hash together in the same results..

Thanks in advance for your help.

Derek.

Comment: Select CompanyPK, (SELECT hashbytes('sha1', (SELECT * From Company Where CompanyPK = 'f5dba28b-ae3b-407a-807c-068acde88298' FOR XML RAW))) as [Hash] From Company Where CompanyPK = 'f5dba28b-ae3b-407a-807c-068acde88298'

Comment: Answered my own question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select CompanyPK, 
(SELECT hashbytes('sha1', 
    (SELECT * From Company 
     Where CompanyPK = 'f5dba28b-ae3b-407a-807c-068acde88298' FOR XML RAW))) 
as [Hash] 
From Company 
Where CompanyPK = 'f5dba28b-ae3b-407a-807c-068acde88298'
```

Sorry to waste your time :)